# behat.yml throw error : The reserved indicator "%" cannot start a plain scalar;

Tags: php, yaml, bdd, behat

I start to use behat to test my application. I have the latest version that is `behat 3.5.0`. Reading the 'latest' doc of behat I tried to change the place from my features to the folder `/app/` like [here](http://behat.org/en/latest/user_guide/configuration.html#custom-autoloading) in the official doc. So I make the same and edit my `behat.yml` to :

```
default:
    autoload:
        '': %paths.base%/app/features/bootstrap
```

unfortunately when I run behat I get this error :

```
The reserved indicator "%" cannot start a plain scalar; you need to quote the scalar at line 3 (near "'': %paths.base%
/app/features/bootstrap").
```

Do you have any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 4):

This has been reported on their repo, the documentation isn't correct.

https://github.com/Behat/Behat/issues/1216

You have to surround it with quotes when using variables:

```
default:
autoload:
    '': '%paths.base%/app/features/bootstrap'
```